# Install Postgis in cpanel with an already installed PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, cpanel, postgis

How can i install Postgis in cpanel with an already installed PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can install PostGIS from cPanel.

I use PostGIS as part of a shared hosting environment (love [A2 Hosting](http://www.a2hosting.com/) - since PostGIS is definitely not available on many hosts) - and A2 took care of the installation for me.

If you're installing it on your own server, dump your db, reinstall Postgres with the PostGIS extension as a package, then restore your data.

Good luck!